# Postgresql dblink

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Trying to be lazy when looking at an example

```
SELECT realestate.address, realestate.parcel, s.sale_year, s.sale_amount, 
        FROM realestate INNER JOIN 
                dblink('dbname=somedb port=5432 host=someserver 
                user=someuser password=somepwd',
                'SELECT parcel_id, sale_year, 
                    sale_amount FROM parcel_sales')
            AS s(parcel_id char(10),sale_year int, sale_amount int)
```

Is there a way of getting the AS section filled in from the table?

I'm copying data from tables of the same name and structure on different servers.
If I can get the structure to copy from the existing table, it will save me a lot of time

Thanks
  Bruce

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: No. See the doc:

> Since dblink can be used with any query, it is declared to return record, rather than specifying any particular set of columns. This means that **you must specify the expected set of columns** in the calling query — otherwise PostgreSQL would not know what to expect.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib-dblink-function.html

---

Edit: by the way, for a table or a view, you can get the fields name and type in a first query:

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'your_table_or_view';
```

You could then use it to fill the fields declaration.

Alexis

Comment: Yes but can you do it as
AS (select column_name  
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'your_table_or_view')

Comment: No, you cannot do it so directly. But all you have to do is write a simple PLPGSQL function to build your query string and execute it.